# Facebook Graph API - getting an access token with curl

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, curl

So I'm basically trying to get an access token in order to access my notifications in a python program, but for now I'm testing out the API calls with curl. According to the docs I can get an access token with the following call:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app_id}
    &redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
    &response_type=token
```

and the access token will be in the URL. When I enter that URL into the browser I see the access token become part of the URL like this

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#
    access_token={access_token}
    &expires_in=5161819
```

but then it quickly turns into `https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_` for some reason, so I can't even get to the `access_token` parameter unless I copy it really quickly.

When I run

```
curl -I "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app_id}
    &redirect_uri="https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token"
```

I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Pragma: no-cache
Location: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=999555493407999&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.3%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26response_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%3D999555493407999%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Facebook-API-Version: v2.3
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html
X-FB-Debug: Q16UqHelnUEt92dEhJKvqpShIycQCbQinV8tD3eKOt/byMdsC4/yVZl49pboyWhdUJAfH/tuZ5hKTZnM6Z/eLw==
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2015 03:04:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

The `location` parameter there doesn't contain the `access_token` either and contains some stuff about an error. Basically I can't make heads or tails of any of this Graph API stuff and I'm stll scratching my head trying to generate a simple access token. I'd like to be able to do it from a terminal window alone rather than work through a browser if at all possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't. You have to use a browser

Comment: The actual login part has to happen inside a browser. You can not do that via cURL. // If you only want an access token for testing purposes, then go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/